# Javascript regex (no look behind) to split on / preceded by word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split the string `"/home/noit/"` to become `["/", "home/", "noit/"]` - every component must end in a slash.

I tried this `'/home/noit/'.split(/\b(?=\/)/)` which gives me `["/home", "/noit", "/"]` which is reverse of what I was trying to get.

Is it possible to split with regex to get `["/", "home/", "noit/"]`?

Comment: Try `s.match(/[^\/]*(?:\/|$)/g)`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - but gave me blank string at the end `[ "/", "home/", "noit/", "" ]`. I was trying to do for leanring purposes.

Comment: Then use a more cumbersome `s.match(/(?!$)[^\/]*(?:\/|$)/g)`. Or `/(?!$)[^\/]*\/?/g`

Comment: Just curious, why do you not want lookbehind?

Comment: @blhsing - javascript doesnt support look-behind, until the very most recent engines.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew very much - is it possible to do this with `split` though? Im trying to learn regex splits.

Comment: Only with a lookbehind, `/(?<=\/)/`

Comment: @Noitidart I'm quite sure that Javascript's support for lookbehind started at the same time it started supporting lookahead. So why are you OK with lookahead patterns but not lookbehind?

Comment: Oh darn, thanks @WiktorStribiżew - it was a nice learning lesson!

Comment: @blhsing lookbehind showing to have sparse support :( - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: does `'/home/noit/'.match(/[^\/]*\//g)` meet your need?

Comment: This may be helpful: [Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)

Comment: Yes thank you @Neverever! It works but I was trying to learn split very much.

Comment: Thanks @vsemozhetbyt thats a really cool article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works, using a word boundary `\b` followed by a positive lookahead excluding the slash:

```js
const x = '/home/noit/';
console.log(x.split(/\b(?=[^\/])/));
```

Comment: Oh wow this so really cool thank you! It seems the regex split works differently, its not excluding those elements as a regular `.split('/')` would, is this true? I'm trying to understand the split with regex, may you please sahre some words that might help me understand.

Comment: Oh gosh look at your code really made me understand this!! So even `'/home/noit/'.split(/\b(?=\w)/)` this works! Thank you @jo_va!